# Cannot reference type definitions for d3

Tags: visual-studio, d3.js, typescript

I'm new to typescript and d3. I try to create a simple bar chart in Visual Studio but im struggling to reference the type definitions of d3.
My project structure looks like this:

[image]

And in my app.ts, I have d3 code:

```
class BarChart {
    render(data) {
        let array = [];
        for (var key in data) {
            array.push(data[key]);           
        }   

        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
            width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        ....
```

The compiler writes: Cannot find name 'd3'.
Makes sense, since the type definitions are missing.

So I have installed the type definitions with: npm install --save @types/d3
It has downloaded several folders with d.ts files:

[image]

But now I don't know how I can reference the type definitions so that the errors go away.

Comment: `import * as d3 from 'd3';` at the top of your app.ts file?

Comment: Then it says:
Error TS2307 Cannot find module 'd3'.

Comment: Like paul said the problem is not with the definitions, it's with the module itself. Did you do `npm install d3 --save`?

Comment: I did it now. It has downloaded even more d3 folders. I think I need to reference this d3 stuff somehow. I mean how should Visual Studio find d3? My d3 stuff is in C:/Users/NMO/node_modules and my solution is on Desktop. So it makes sense to me that it can't find d3 module.

Comment: When I put the my d3 code between <scipt> tags in the html file, then it works. But when I put it in a separate .ts file, then it doesn't work.